# SQL Copying Rows & With Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, replication

I'm trying to copy a set of data that resembles the following:

ADDRESS:

```
| ADDRESS_CODE | ADDRESS_TYPE | COLUMNCOLUMCOLUMN... (40 columns or so)
|   DEFAULT    |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   002        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   003        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   004        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   005        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
```

CONTACT:

```
| CONTACT_CODE |   VENDOR_ID  | COLUMNCOLUMNCOLUMN... (30 columns or so)
|   DEFAULT    |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   002        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
```

I'm using several SQL queries to try and get this to work out, but it keeps replicating only the Default and 002 from contact 5 times, or only doing one of the lines in an infinite loop.  I'm inserting into the contact table.

Here's my desired result for CONTACT:

```
| CONTACT_CODE |   VENDOR_ID  | COLUMNCOLUMNCOLUMN... (30 columns or so)
|   DEFAULT    |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   002        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   003        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   004        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
|   005        |   VENDOR1    | DATA DATA DATA
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've been using something like the following query:

```
select c.vendor_id, c.contact_code, a.address_code 
from contact c, address a
inner join contact
on c.contact_code <> a.address_code
and c.vendor_id = a.address_type
group by c.vendor_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into contact (CONTACT_CODE,VENDOR_ID,<COLUMNS list>)

select Address_code, Address_type, <COLUMNS list>
from ADDRESS a
left join contact c
   on a.address_code=c.contact_code
   and a.address_type=c.vendor_id
where c.contact_code is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left outer join between address and contacts table to get this desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT` statement with condition:

```
INSERT INTO contact c
  (contact_code, vendor_id, < OTHER COLUMNS >)
  SELECT a.address_code, a.address_type, a.OTHER COLUMNS,
    FROM address a
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM CONTACT c, address a
           WHERE a.address_code = c.contact_code
             AND a.address_type = c.vendor_id);
```

I haven't tested it though..